# While running a npm install i am getting following error

Tags: npm-install

The error is

> E/downloader - { Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND modala.venkatesh modala.venkatesh:80

Comment: Are you running in a VM or natively?

Comment: native ubuntu 16

Comment: Ouch -- just had a similar issue while running a VM (W7) that was solved by changing the settings for the network, but for a real OS [and especially Linux] I have no idea. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following commands :

```
npm config set proxy false
npm cache clean
```

If there is no proxy , below commands may also fetch you the expected results :

```
npm config set proxy null
npm config set https-proxy null
```

Comment: Already i tried above commands for the existing proxy but no use any alternative?